# My window manager runs quite slowly

Tags: window-manager

**I've noticed that my OS is running a bit slow in the GUI**, when I run programs they are just fine. Someone told me I should use a different window manager, but that person did not follow up on how to install said different windows manager. **so how do I find a window manager that I like and install it?**